# How to check if there is a transitive orientation for a given undirected graph?

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, adjacency-matrix, undirected-graph

An undirected graph has a transitive orientation if its edges can be oriented in such a way that if (x, y) and (y, z) are two edges in the resulting directed graph, there also exists an edge (x, z) in the resulting directed graph.

I am working with real food web networks and I need to check if a dense undirected graph (which models competition in the food web) has a transitive orientation. The undirected graph is represented as an adjacency matrix in Java.

EDIT:

For example,
[for this undirected graph,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuAzL.jpg)

We can orient the edges in [this way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cL63n.jpg). So, this graph has a transitive orientation.

Comment: I answered, but then I noticed that you're using "undirected graph" and "directed graph" in the discussion. Is that a typo, or what?

Comment: After orienting the edges of the undirected graph, the resulting graph is a directed graph.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something. As you've defined "having a TO," I believe any path in the original undirected graph must lie in a complete subgraph. Consequently, every connected component must be a complete graph for the original graph to have a TO. It's pretty easy to check that. If I have this wrong, examples of incomplete graphs having a TO would be helpful.

Comment: @PratikKoirala What do you mean by orienting an edge?

Comment: @nbro Orienting an edge simply means assigning or choosing a direction to the edge.

Comment: @Gene I have edited my post with an example and its not a complete graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking at is [comparability graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparability_graph). This class of graph is also known as "transitively orientable graphs", but this is not the most common name. 
For recognition of this class, look at the [graphclasses website](http://www.graphclasses.org/classes/gc_72.html).

Comment: Yes, I have read about comparability graph. Do you know of a simple implementation for this, that would be helpful?

Comment: You can have a look at chapter 5 of book "Algorithmic Graph Theory and Perfect Graphs" by Golumbic, it is dedicated to comparability graphs.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into it.